# PDFKit iOS11 Swift 4 How to display tables?

Tags: swift, ios11, pdfkit

I really like the new PDFKit in iOS11.
Just wanted to know if there is any annotation or easy way to display a table with content. Or if I really have to draw it textbox by textbox. I didnt found any informations here or in the WWDC 2017.
How are you doing this guys? Thanks for any help.
best,
Pasquale

Comment: i dont know about PDFKit never use once but. before ios 11 i have make one PDF like tablecontent. go through this link https://github.com/vishalkalola1/DrawPDF

Comment: Thank you! It really looks like PDFKit is not the right framework to generate a new PDF from scratch in iOS. Are there more examples like adding images to the pdf page etc.?

Comment: Write Image into PDF YourImage.draw(in: rect)

Comment: @VishalPatel , Hi Hi, Would please help me in my question too if you solve this problem please ? Realy Really appreciate you and Thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609831/navigating-text-box-on-a-pdf-is-not-working-any-more-after-ios-13-seems-gestur

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh sure i will check it later. but didn't send you immediate solution.

Comment: Can I count on you or your group to help me in this project? I can send you emails. and your requests will be accepted and appreciate .  thank you. Really .@VishalPatel

Comment: sure you can. @nedaDerakhshesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedbacks.
I found something helpfull from Apple for the new PDFKit to play around and find the right annotations. But it looks like to draw a new pdf from scratch PDFKit is not the right framework, still have to use Quartz 2D. Sorry, I thought PDFKit is like a Kit for everything.

Here is what the PDF Annotations Editor:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Hi I need help in how to use annotations and run something like editor to create pdfkit. I wonder If you have any information which it could be helpful or if you know please help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609287/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-image-which-taken-by-camera-with-pdfkit